# Trying to track down why httpd would be trying to connect to a tor port

Tags: httpd, apache-2.4, selinux, tor

I'm seeing occasional selinux denied messages in my logs that I believe indicate that the httpd process is trying to connect to a tor port:

> type=AVC msg=audit(1423247604.799:1966): avc:  **denied**  { **name_connect** } for  pid=25650 comm="**httpd**" dest=**9050** scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:**tor_port_t**:s0 tclass=tcp_socket

This server is not directly connected to the Internet.  All the HTTP requests are proxied from a server that is connected to the Internet with HAProxy to pass requests back and forth.  The web sites on the server are WordPress sites in a few different virtual hosts.  None of the sites are very busy.

I don't want to turn on the sebool to allow httpd to network connect to just anywhere, and this looks like a good reason not to.

My concern is why the httpd process is trying to do this at all and that the server may be compromised somehow.

Any suggestions for how to track down the source that's causing these network connection attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Check the httpd error log for any indication what may have failed.

You could also simply grep for the port number (9050) through the WordPress source code, on the off chance that it gives you a clue to what is going on.